# iOS - Change the size of a CALayer when clicked on a button then get back to the original size

Tags: ios, core-graphics, core-animation, calayer

I created a CALayer and a button, when I click on the button the CALayer corner radius is changed, then when I click on the button again the corner radius is back to its original radius. What I want is to do the same thing with the CALayer's size 
here is the code I use:

```
layer.cornerRadius = (layer.cornerRadius==0.0f) ? 37.0f : 0.0f;
```

Any help please?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare property

```
@property (assign, nonatomic) CGRect originalSize;
```

and add code below:

```
if (CGRectEqualToRect(_originalSize, CGRectZero)){ 
  _originalSize = [layer bounds];//store original bounds in first time
}
[layer setBounds:CGRectEqualToRect(_originalSize, layer.bounds) ? CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100) : _originalSize];
```